# Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas based on YT Tutorial

Tags: error

I red the other Threads about this case, but couldn't fixed the problem.
I got this tutorial for Scmart contracts:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coQ5dg8wM2o&feature=youtu.be

However the problem is that I get this error when I use "truffle migrate:

```
Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?
    at ABICoder.decodeParameters (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js:226:1)
    at Contract._decodeMethodReturn (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:465:1)
    at Method.outputFormatter (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:818:1)
    at Method.formatOutput (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-contract/~/web3-core-method/src/index.js:163:1)
    at sendTxCallback (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-contract/~/web3-core-method/src/index.js:473:1)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-core-requestmanager/src/index.js:147:1
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:112:1
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-providers-http/src/index.js:96:1)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:318:1)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:289:47)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:198:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1139:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:17)
Truffle v5.0.2 (core: 5.0.2)
Node v11.15.0
```

I use Ubuntu 18.04

Could anyone help me, actually I did the same in the Video, untill the problem in min 18.

Cheers

Comment: Can you include the source code in the question?

Comment: Hey. actually it is this github:

https://github.com/dappuniversity/eth-todo-list

Comment: I can delpoy what inside the repository on Ganache v2.1.1

$ truffle version
Truffle v5.1.0 (core: 5.1.0)
Solidity v0.5.12 (solc-js)
Node v8.11.3
Web3.js v1.2.2